# How to handle negative iterator passed in function?

Tags: ruby, rotation

I am working on a manual rotate function in Ruby. But I ran into issue there are negative offsets passed in some examples. Is it possible to iterate from a negative number up to a specified index(not sure what that index would be)?

```
def my_rotate(arr, offset=1)
  if offset < 1 
    for i in offset
      arr.push(arr.shift)
    end
  else 
    for i in 1..offset
      arr.push(arr.shift)
    end
  end  
  arr
end
```

Comment: Why not ditch this functional/proceedural approach and use the built in methods on Array? E.g. `arr.rotate(2)`

Comment: Also, the [documentation for rotate](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) has the source for the method, so you can see pretty easily the algorithm/approach used.

Answer (score 2):

Following with your code, you can use [Array#pop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-pop) and [Array#unshift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-unshift) (which are the opposites of [Array#push](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-push) and [Array#shift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-shift)):

```
def my_rotate(array, offset=1)
  arr = array.dup

  if offset < 1 
    for i in 1..offset.abs
      arr.unshift(arr.pop)
    end
  else 
    for i in 1..offset
      arr.push(arr.shift)
    end
  end  
  arr
end
```

Notice the change in line 5 `for i in 1..offset.abs` to be able to loop the array, and the addition of line 2 `arr = array.dup` to prevent the original array from being mutated.

Comment: Thanks going to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much how [Array#rotate](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) does it (in C).

**Code**

```
class Array
  def my_rotate(n=1)
    n %= self.size
    self[n..-1].concat(self[0,n])
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]

arr.my_rotate  0   #=> [1,2,3,4]

arr.my_rotate      #=> [2, 3, 4, 1]
arr.my_rotate  1   #=> [2, 3, 4, 1]
arr.my_rotate  4   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.my_rotate  5   #=> [2, 3, 4, 1]
arr.my_rotate  9   #=> [2, 3, 4, 1]

arr.my_rotate -1   #=> [4, 1, 2, 3]
arr.my_rotate -4   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.my_rotate -5   #=> [4, 1, 2, 3]
arr.my_rotate -9   #=> [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Explanation**

The line

```
n %= self.size
```

which Ruby's parser expands to

```
n = n % self.size
```

converts `n` to an integer between `0` and `self.size - 1`. Moreover, it does so for both positive and negative values of `n`.

The line

```
self[n..-1].concat(self[0,n])
```

appends the first `n` elements of `arr` to an array comprised of the last `arr.size - n` elements of `arr`. The resulting array is then returned by the method.

If you do not wish to add this method to the class `Array` you could of course define it `def my_rotate(arr, n)...`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Really appreciate it.